# jQuery - how to get different value from hidden input id inside same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get different value from hidden input id inside same class. Here is some example code of html and jQuery that I'm trying to create.

```
 <li>
   <div class="test"><img src="course.png"/><p class="text">Computer</p>
    <span class="list">
      <p>Course 1 <input type="hidden" id="id1" value="1"></p>
      <p>Course 2 <input type="hidden" id="id2" value="2"></p>
      <p>Course 3 <input type="hidden" id="id3" value="3"></p>
    </span> 
   </div>
  </li>
```

Code that I'm trying to create

```
$(".test p").click(function(){
    var id= $(this).find('#id1').val(); 
    var id= $(this).find('#id2').val();
    var id= $(this).find('#id3').val();
    alert(id);    // will return value 1 or 2 or 3 if click on any course
});
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: solved by members below :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use "id" as a var name.

This should work:

```
$(".test p").click(function(){
    var myID = $(this).find('input').val(); 
    alert(myID);    // will return value 1 or 2 or 3 if click on any course
});
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3rsc5ycd/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

its better to have class for your p and input tags and instead of id use them

```
 <li>
   <div class="test"><img src="course.png"/><p class="text">Computer</p>
    <span class="list">
      <p class="myCourse">Course 1 <input type="hidden" class="myCourseVal" value="1"></p>
      <p class="myCourse">Course 2 <input type="hidden" class="myCourseVal" value="2"></p>
      <p class="myCourse">Course 3 <input type="hidden" class="myCourseVal" value="3"></p>
    </span> 
   </div>
  </li>

$(".test .myCourse").click(function(){
    var myValue = $(this).find('.myCourseVal').val()); 
    alert(myValue);
});
```

It's better to use class instead of  `input tag`, so if in the future you add other input, you get your value correctly base on what you want.

If you don't use class for you desire `p`s if you click on `Computer` your code will start to run.

If you want to have your course values that there is in you course name:

```
$(".test .text").click(function(){
   var x = [];
   foreach('.myCourse',function(){
       x.push($(this).find('.myCourseVal').val(); 
   })
   alert(x);
});
```

Comment: thanks hadi,your code is inspire to me to be better,I also have noted your advice and method. :D